# Lazy loading of the content

Tags: java, javascript, json, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have two entities : `User` and `Post` (relation one-to-many). `Post` fields: `id`, `creationDate`, `title`, `content`, `user`.

Data is stored in the database and accessed via Hibernate.

I have a controller to pass Post object as a JSON to JavaScript. Then it is shown on the web page. But it is not always necessary to pass all the `Post` fields. For ex., I need to show to the user only title and creation date, and if the user presses the button `Show content`, only then I need to show post content (which I want to request from server only when it is need to show).

So here is a problem: How can I implement *lazy* initialization of the content field in Post object? Should I write two methods in my controller: one for generating JSON with list of Posts and setting content field to `null` or empty `String`, and another to pass only content string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make post content an object and a single table in db.

It looks like the following in java:

```
public class Post {

  ...


  PostContent postContent;
}
```

Comment: yep, I think that would be pretty handy. As I use Jackson, I can annotate this field with @JsonSerialize(PostToJson.class) so that in JSON there will be only Id's of the post contents. And then pass to server id of the post content to get it.

Answer (score 1):

First you may try to initialize the lazy collection at the DAO via `Hibernate.initialize(lazyCollection)`. If it didn't work then either use `FetchType.EAGER` or keep the session open during request and the collection should be fetched when needed.