# Java Spring Boot: Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to build an endpoint to my API to update the records in the database.

The class is the following:

```
    @Entity
    public class Recipe {
        private @Id Long id;
        ...         
        
        @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @CollectionTable(name = "recipe_parameters", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
        @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
        @Column(name = "value")
        private Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        ...
}
```

I need to update the values in the Map "parameters"
This is the endpoint in the controller:

```
@PutMapping("/recipes/{id}")
public Recipe updateRecipe(@RequestBody Recipe recipe, @PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
          .map(r -> {
              r.setCodiceFamigliaDUT(recipe.getCodiceFamigliaDUT());
              r.setParameters(recipe.getParameters());
              r.setUltima_modifica(new Date());
              return repository.save(r);
          })
          .orElseGet(() -> {
            recipe.setId(id);
            return repository.save(recipe);
          });
}
```

The recipe.getParameters() line gives the error.

There are many similar questions but nothing seems to work.
I tried the following:

1. Add @Transactional to the method. This doesn't seem to change anything.
2. add Hibernate.initialize(recipe.getParameters()) before the line that gives the error.

I'd prefer to keep it LAZY for performances reasons, is there a way to fix this error?

EIDT

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'mqttBeans.handler.serviceActivator.handler' for component 'mqttBeans']; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.en4.demo.model.Recipe.parameters, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.messageArrived(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:394) ~[spring-integration-mqtt-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:519) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:417) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:214) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.en4.demo.model.Recipe.parameters, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:612) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap.clear(PersistentMap.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at com.en4.demo.model.Recipe.setParameters(Recipe.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.en4.demo.controller.RecipeController.lambda$1(RecipeController.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at com.en4.demo.controller.RecipeController.updateRecipe(RecipeController.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.en4.demo.controller.TestSessionController.addTest(TestSessionController.java:428) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.en4.demo.mqtt.MqttBeans$1.handleMessage(MqttBeans.java:104) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:59) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried Hibernate's `@LazyCollection`? Although I believe it's set to Lazy collect by default since Hiberante 3.0, so it will likely don't make a difference. Also, please post the stack trace of the error.

Comment: @JettoMartínez added stacktrace

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

Comment: Where have you put @Transactional? On the findById? I've had a similar problem and using a layer annotated with service that call the repository with the method annotated with @Transactional solved the problem

Comment: I had a similar problem with collections but fortunately resolved it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428167/573032).

Comment: I added the Transactional at the updateRecipe method, above @PutMapping